# Different code / config in Release & Debug build (Obj-C)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, debugging, release

I'm writing a Cocoa app in Objective C that's communicating with a webservice and I want it to connect to a sandbox in debug mode and to the real webservice in release mode. All I need is to change on line of code where an object that holds the configuration gets instantiated (with a different init-message and different parameters).

So how would I swap a line of code for Release or Debug mode?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could check for `#ifdef DEBUG`, but I would recommend you don't do that.

There are a lots of differences between Debug and Release builds.  Different compiler optimizations, different sets of symbols, etc...

Invariably, you are going to find yourself in a situation where you want to run the Release build against your sandbox for debugging purposes.... and your debug build against the production webservice because some customer has a problem that only reproduces in Release mode.

So, for that, I'd suggest a user default.  See `NSUserDefaults`.

Note that simple user defaults can be set from the command line.

Thus, you could do something like:

```
/path/to/Myapp.app/Contents/Macos/Myapp -ServerMode Debug
```

Comment: Interesting technique, I'll have to remember that.

Comment: Thanks for this tip! Your terminal command didn't really work for me. I found "defaults write my.bundle.identifier SandboxModeFlag -bool YES" to be working fine for me.

Answer (score 8):

You can use config-specific defines to change the code that's executed.  Read about how to [define a preprocessor symbol in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367368/how-to-define-a-preprocessor-symbol-in-xcode) first.  Then, in your code, do something like this:

```
#if DEBUG_MODE
#define BACKEND_URL @"http://testing.myserver.com"
#else
#define BACKEND_URL @"http://live.myserver.com"
#end

NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:BACKEND_URL]];
```

Comment: Although I prefered bbum's solution, I now understand how this works and will keep it in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First, define a preprocessor symbol that is only set in your Debug build configuration, as per the question [367368](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367368/how-to-define-a-preprocessor-symbol-in-xcode) - call it, say, DEBUG. Then you can do

```
#ifdef DEBUG
  // Code that only compiles in debug configuration
#else
  // Code that compiles in other configurations (i.e. release)
#endif
```