# Find release/debug mode in runtime?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Different code / config in Release & Debug build (Obj-C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406175/different-code-config-in-release-debug-build-obj-c)

Is there a way to find whether application is running in release or debug mode in objetive-c?

Comment: I think its not duplicate because I want to find it on runtime.

Answer (score 0):

http://jomnius.blogspot.com/2011/09/how-to-do-dynamic-debug-logging-in.html This seems to be leading me to right direction.