# Updating a free App requires paying if the update is not free?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I have a free App that I am about to update. After the update it will not be free anymore.

People who got my App while it was free - will they have to pay in order to get the new paid version?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, only initial app installation can be paid - all updates are free. The possible option to introduce paying in your app is to use [in-app purchase](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) functionality.

Comment: Problem with that is that new users would have to use in-app purchase too. I think the only/best way to do it would be to start with Free 1.0. Then introduce version 1.0.1 (which is also free) which installs a mark (preference or file) saying the user got the free version. Then have 1.1 which costs money; if the mark is present, introduce in-app purchase. Otherwise, give the new user full access.

Comment: The problem then is that users might delete the app and reinstall later. The user would than have not the preference set correctly and hence would be asked to pay again.

Comment: Yes, this is problematic.  For more discussion on this topic, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575965/transition-an-existing-paid-for-app-to-free-version-with-in-app-purchase

Answer (score 1):

As long as it's the same app (not published as a separate one) then I believe it will still be free.  iTunes will still consider those people to own the app, so changing the price wouldn't affect them.