# Determine if user bought the app

Tags: ios

Is it possible to determine if the user bought the app or not?

I have an app which is not free. I plan to make app with no-fee with ads. But I don't want to show ads who already purchased the app. Is it possible to disable ads for the people purchased previously?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Check this already answered here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19390810/change-paid-app-to-free-but-know-if-user-previously-purchased-it

Answer (score 1):

Not through any official API.

The easiest solution would be to push out an update (still paid) which sets a flag in `NSUserDefaults`, wait a sufficient time for your users to update, and then use that to distinguish between original users (who paid) and new ones (who got it free).

However, there are a bunch of problems with that.  Just to name two:

- users don't update consistently, so you'll miss a bunch of people
- people who delete and reinstall the app will lose the flag

The way you would normally maintain a version of an app with ads and one without is either to use a 'Lite' version (discouraged) or remove the ads with In-App Purchases.

If you want to do the latter, though, you run into the same problem.  Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575965/transition-an-existing-paid-for-app-to-free-version-with-in-app-purchase) for some more info on that approach.

Comment: By using keychain instead of user defaults you can solve the "delete and reinstall" problem.

Comment: @Sulthan: AFAIK, keychain comes with iOS 7.0.3 which may not be applicable to many users.

Comment: @TurkdoganTasdelen You are terribly wrong. Keychain has been there since very old versions of iOS.

Comment: Thanks @sapi, it seems that there is not an obvious solution to this problem. I will go with http://stackoverflow.com/a/19391432/591868. App will not show ads to iOS 5/6 users.

Comment: @Sulthan: Your are right. I had checked wrong document. My bad, sorry about that.