# How can I access a user-defined Xcode build setting?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

If I added a user-defined setting in my build configuration, how can I read that setting in my Objective-C code?

I have two files in my project, `debug.plist` and `release.plist`. I want my `MainApp.m` file to read one of these files based on which build configuration is running. I set up a user-defined setting named "filename" in both the Debug and Release configurations to point to the appropriate file. But I don't know how my `MainApp.m` file can read the filename variable from the current running configuration.

Answer (score 48):

Here's what I did, I'm not 100% sure if this is what you're after:

1. Go into the build Settings panel and choose the gear icon in the bottom left: add User-Defined Setting
2. Create your user defined setting, for example:

   ```
   MY_LANG -> en_us
   ```
3. Then, in the Preprocessor Macro's setting, you can reference that value:

   ```
   LANGCODE="$(MY_LANG)"
   ```

Now you can refer to LANGCODE in all your source files, and it will be whatever you filled out in your custom build setting. I realize that there's a level of indirection here, but that is intentional in my case: my XCode project contains a bunch of different targets/configurations with their own preprocessor macro's. I don't want to have to go into all of those, just to change the language code. In fact, I define the language code on the project level. I also use MY_LANG in a couple scripts, so *just* a preprocessor macro wouldn't do. There may be a smarter way, but this works for me.

Comment: ok, I can follow the first two steps, however I cannot figure out what you mean by Preprocessor Macro setting in step three. I tried adding it to the GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367368/how-to-define-a-preprocessor-symbol-in-xcode however that did not work

Comment: Another way of doing this is after you created a user setting, go to Build Phases tab, and for the source file where the setting is intedend to be read, add: `-D'LANGCODE=@"$(MY_LANG)"'`.

Comment: If you define macro for a **string** in the build settings, don't forget to escape quotes like this `LANGCODE=@\"$(MY_LANG)\"`

Comment: This worked for me in Build Settings for a revision that needs to be a string: `VERSION_REV=\"000000\"`   Thanks to @DanSkeel for his note as that helped.

Answer (score 44):

You can access your user-defined build setting at run-time (as suggested in a comment by @JWWalker)

1. Add an entry to your `Info.plist` file, and set it to your User-defined Build Setting

   ```
   MySetting -> ${MYSETTING}
   ```
2. Read its value from code

   Objective-C

   ```
   [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"MySetting"];
   ```

   **[Edit]** Swift

   ```
   guard let mySetting = 
     Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "MySetting") as? String 
       else { print("MySetting not found") }
   ```

Comment: Is there a way to access the user-defined setting without adding an entry to Info.plist?

Answer (score 23):

Swift 4

Lets say "filename" is the String you need in your app.

Add filename=YOUR_STRING to user-defined setting(for debug and release).

And add filename = $(filename) to info.plist.

Then in Swift code:

```
if let filename = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["filename"] as? String {
    // do stuff with filename
} 
else {
    // filename wasn't able to be casted to String
}
```

Comment: This works! Swift 4.2 (Xcode 10.0). Don't forget second step with Info.plist as I did.

Comment: Works, so far the simplest solution I found.

Comment: Excellent approach. Works great and is by far the most Swift friendly solution!

Comment: You really shouldn't for force casting to a String here. I changed the code to make it an optional with else statement.

Comment: I used if-let here, but guard-let works too.

Answer (score 9):

Your code can't read arbitrary build settings.  You need to use preprocessor macros.

EDIT: For example, in the target settings for the Debug configuration, you could add `DEBUGGING=1` in the Preprocessor Macros build setting, and not define DEBUGGING in the Release configuration.  Then in your source code you could do things like:

```
#if DEBUGGING
  use this file
#else
  use the other one
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks, JWWalker, can you show me how to define a preprocessor macros specifically for xcode project?

Comment: OK, I added an example to my answer.

Comment: P.S.  There is one way to use a user-defined setting: Check "Expand Build Settings in Info.plist File", then you can use `$MYSETTING` in the Info.plist file.

Answer (score 6):

I tried **zmippie** suggestion but it didn't work for me.

I got it working with this:

```
${MY_LANG}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is still stuck looking for how to do preprocessor macros, look for the Apple LLVM - Preprocessing section in Build Settings. Under it, you will see a section called Preprocessor Macros.

This is where by default, Xcode inserts the DEBUG=1 macro for the debug build configuration.

You can add your own here, and give them different values for debug, release and any custom build configs you may have.

To add one, double-click on the current value list for the config you want, and it'll display a nice little editor with one macro on each line. Just add your own macro name, and give it a value the same way the DEBUG one is done.

These can be checked during the preprocessor build phase using #if, #ifdef etc. to provide conditional code or values.

Hope that helps.