# access user defined settings in swift code

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I added a user defined settings in project build settings:

[image]

[image]

How can I access the value of `my_name` in my iOS project swift code?

Comment: Possibly Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968919/how-can-i-access-a-user-defined-xcode-build-setting

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding the `User Defined` setting.

If you ant to provide specific value by environment you just use :

- for Swift :

  Other Swift Flag : `-D my_value`
- For Objc :

  preprocessor macro : `my_value=1`

Then in your code you can do

```
#if my_value
    some code here
#endif
```

Comment: where can I find "Custom Swift Flag"?

Comment: It's `other swift flags` in the build settings pane