# Maps custom Xcode configuration to NativeBuildType in Kotlin Multi-platform

Tags: ios, xcode, kotlin, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

I am reading [cocoapods](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-cocoapods.html#add-and-configure-kotlin-cocoapods-gradle-plugin) and I see this two lines in gradle file. Can someone explain me in details. What is the purpose of this lines?

```
xcodeConfigurationToNativeBuildType["CUSTOM_DEBUG"] = NativeBuildType.DEBUG
xcodeConfigurationToNativeBuildType["CUSTOM_RELEASE"] = NativeBuildType.RELEASE
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the iOS app has two configurations: debug and release.

You can add more configurations as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842746/adding-a-build-configuration-in-xcode). Using different configurations, you can create different versions of your app: each build parameter in Xcode can have different values depending on the configuration, including [user-defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968919/how-can-i-access-a-user-defined-xcode-build-setting).

For example, it is useful to have an AppStore configuration and a release configuration for local testing, which can use different endpoints, api keys, etc.

`xcodeConfigurationToNativeBuildType` lets the multiplatform kotlin plugin know which build type a particular custom configuration should be built with - the debug configuration is slower, but gives more debugging options.