# How to create a singleton with #define in XCode4?

Tags: xcode, c-preprocessor

I am trying to follow a [tutorial for interfacing Game Center](http://ganbarugames.com/2011/07/cocos2d-game-center/), that uses the Apple Documentation and Matt Gallagher's ["singleton" document](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html).

However, XCode is emitting polite but vehement protests, lodging its complaints as "Data definition has no type or storage class". In other words, it thinks that `SYNTHESIZE_SINGLETON_FOR_CLASS_HEADER(GameCenterManager);` is a method declaration lacking a type. 
Some StackOverflow archaeology brought to my attention a change to [XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367368/how-to-define-a-preprocessor-symbol-in-xcode).

However, it lets me quite perplexed. Should I really create, deep inside the compiler settings, two entries, one of which is at least 600 characters long, that basically will contain what currently is inside a nice, neat header file?

Follows the source of said header file, written by Matt Gallagher, which would then go into two places:

```
#define SYNTHESIZE_SINGLETON_FOR_CLASS_HEADER(__CLASSNAME__)    \
\
+ (__CLASSNAME__ *)shared##__CLASSNAME__;   \
+ (void)purgeShared##__CLASSNAME__;
```

and

```
#define SYNTHESIZE_SINGLETON_FOR_CLASS(classname) \
\
static classname *shared##classname = nil; \
 \
+ (classname *)shared##classname \
{ \
@synchronized(self) \
{ \
    if (shared##classname == nil) \
    { \
        shared##classname = [[self alloc] init]; \
    } \
} \
 \
return shared##classname; \
} \
 \
+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone \
{ \
@synchronized(self) \
{ \
    if (shared##classname == nil) \
    { \
        shared##classname = [super allocWithZone:zone]; \
        return shared##classname; \
    } \
} \
 \
return nil; \
  } \
  \
 - (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone \
{ \
return self; \
} \
 \
- (id)retain \
{ \
return self; \
} \
 \
- (NSUInteger)retainCount \
{ \
return NSUIntegerMax; \
} \
 \
- (void)release \
{ \
} \
 \
- (id)autorelease \
{ \
return self; \
}
```

So, where am I mistaken in my understanding?

Comment: I'd question any design where singletons are so common that such a #define is needed (not to mention the drama involved in that singleton implementation).  It is likely to make any kind of future refactoring much more difficult.

Comment: Well, I agree with that, but Gallagher points out that code duplication is bad, and you might need several Singletons anyway. So I'll follow his lead, he's more savvy than I :D

Comment: If code duplication is a sin, so is complexity.   Every singleton I've ever implemented has consisted of a single method; `+sharedInstance`.   That is all that is needed and the rest is noise, hides bugs, and makes refactoring more difficult in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this line into the source file and now it runs fine. As I understand it, if I want to define something I have to use this import to notify the compiler I'm aware of what I'm doing.

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
```

If I'm wrong, feel free to correct me.