# How to tell if a C++ symbol is #defined in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, c-preprocessor

I'm used to Visual C++ which makes it very clear in an `#ifdef` block if the block is going to be compiled or not.

Does Xcode (3) do this too, I couldn't see how?

Comment: What have you tried so far? [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367368/how-to-define-a-preprocessor-symbol-in-xcode) might help you a bit...

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov: I think the OP is talking about the greying out that VS does for blocks that aren't currently applicable, not how to define symbols.

Comment: @minitech Oh I see, thanks, now that makes more sense to me.

Comment: @minitech correct. Ideally not just visually but by hovering over and it telling me the value or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the following screenshot.

[image]

As you can see, Xcode 4 does not apply syntax coloring in the parts that will not be compiled.

Comment: True but if your code doesn't have syntax coloring, it doesn't help... a function call with parameters and no literals or datatypes mentioned. However if I'm unsure, I suppose I can add a dummy line of code like `int x = 123;` and see what happens!