# Fortran 2008 - conditional compilation

Tags: fortran, c-preprocessor, gfortran, conditional-compilation, preprocessor-directive

I need  to use a conditional compilation in Fortran2008. So far I've found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41234703/3801449), but it somehow doesn't work for me and despite compiling my code with `-cpp` flag like this

```
gfortran  -Dconnection_m_EXPORTS -I/home/martin/4Neuro/build/lib  -O2 -std=f2008 -cpp -fPIC   -c /home/martin/4Neuro/src/connection_m.f90 -o CMakeFiles/connection_m.dir/connection_m.f90.o
```

I'm still getting this error

```
/home/martin/4Neuro/src/connection_m.f90:133:13:
             #ifdef TIME_PROFILING
             1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
/home/martin/4Neuro/src/connection_m.f90:136:13:

             #endif
             1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
/home/martin/4Neuro/src/connection_m.f90:143:13:

             #ifdef TIME_PROFILING
             1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
/home/martin/4Neuro/src/connection_m.f90:148:13:

             #endif
             1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
```

Do you know, what am I doing wrong?

My gfortran version is: `GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 6.2.0-5ubuntu12) 6.2.0 20161005`
And my files have the extension `.f90`.

Comment: That looks ok to me. Can you try to create a minimal example? Or post your code?

Comment: Note that the `#` has to be in column 1.

Comment: @Ross You're right, the problem disappeared, when I moved directives to the beginning of lines... Could you, please, write your comment as an answer, so I could accept it?

Comment: Internet points!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preprocessor directives with `#` must have `#` appear in column 1.